# Logging exception without catching it

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to log an unhandled exception in my domain layer without catching it.

I mean that the exception should be thrown after logging to be caught again in upper levels. As you know, throwing has an overhead that I want to avoid.

Any idea in Dotnet platform (C#) ?

Comment: just do `catch(Exception e) { Log(e); throw; }` to release it after logging.

Comment: random thought: if so many exceptions are thrown that the overhead of rethrowing them is _significant_ enough to worry about, wouldn't it be better to reduce the amount of original exceptions? (also: IIRC, the main-overhead of an exception is the stacktrace - which won't be initialised a second time when _rethrowing_?)

Comment: @juharr Thanks but as you see I don't want to throw it again.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann The question is just to show a creative idea ;-) There is no huge amount of exceptions dear Franz <3

Comment: Unhandled exception will crash the application anyway so performance implication should be the least concern. I am not sure what your "unhandled" really means.

Comment: @tia global exception handlers (like middlewares, AppDomain handlers, etc..) will catch unhandled exceptions dude

Comment: Middlewares catch there own exception, and AppDomain.UnhandledException can track unhandled exception but framework like ASP.NET Core will catch all exception in the pipeline so the service wouldn't crash. I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: By the way any type of dotnet application can have a global exception handler maybe manually-implemented or as core-language-feature hence the global exception handling is not the problem. The main problem is to log an exception without catching in bottom layers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new System.Exception("some exception");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex) when (LogUsingSerilogOrNLogOrBla(ex)) { }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception logged, but not handled :), there is no need to throw");
    }
}


public static bool LogUsingSerilogOrNLogOrBla(System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt this has better performance than just catching, logging, and releasing the exception.  Maybe you should create some test benchmarks to see if it is in fact more performant and if so by how much.

Comment: This is not about performance but about logging within a given scope. The when clause is passed when unwinding the stack - and thus within the scope, whereas logging within the catch block is excecuted after the stack unwound. Thus logging within the catch block is not within the scope. If you are concerned about performance avoid exceptions in the first place.